# Can't get vim 8.0 terminal-api to work job-to-vim

Tags: vim, pty

Here is a simple exapmle taken right from the vim docs `:help terminal-api`.

In cwd I have an executable file `run.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("hello")
print("\x1b]51;[\"drop\", \"run.py\"]\x07")
print("world")
```

I open a new instance of vim and type the following:

```
:terminal ./run.py
```

This is what I get in the terminal window:

```
hello

world
```

And the file doesn't get opened.

what am I missing here?

Comment: I've got 8.1.1790 and your code works exactly as described when I run it.

Comment: The `:terminal` was introduced [in Vim 8.1](https://vimhelp.org/version8.txt.html#version-8.1), so I imagine that's the version you're using?

Comment: Sorry for late replies
@larsks So you mean it opens the file as it should?

Comment: @filbranden No, it's actualy `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12); Included patches: 1-1568; Compiled by 'http://www.opensuse.org/'`, and it does have `:terminal` command. So maybe that's why the api doesn't work for me?